# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat dropping $ symbol from key

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, nsexception

I am using NSPredicate to filter the contents of an NSArray of NSDictionary objects. Nothing crazy. I want to check three different values in the dictionary for the same search string. Here is the string I am passing to `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]`:

```
($ECInstanceLabel CONTAINS[c] filterMe) OR (SubLabel1 CONTAINS[c] filterMe) OR (SubLabel2 CONTAINS[c] filterMe)
```

When I execute this, a valid instance of a new NSPredicate is created, but when I do `[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`, the application throws an exception.

The exception is:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't get value for 'ECInstanceLabel' in bindings { }.'
```

I think part of the problem is that my format string specifies that the first dictionary key value is `$ECInstanceLabel` but somehow the `$` is getting escaped. I have tried manually escaping this character but then the program crashes when I try to create the predicate, so I don't think the `$` symbol is recognized as an escapable character.

Any ideas or something obvious I may be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$var` is used in predicates for *variables* that can be substituted later.
If you have a key containing `$` or other special characters then use the `%K` expansion:

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SubLabel1 CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SubLabel2 CONTAINS[c] %@)",
          @"$ECInstanceLabel", searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm]
```

And use the `%@` format for the search term instead of writing it inline, to avoid
errors if the search term contains special characters.

Of course you can use `%@` for *all* keys, but in this case you *need* it only for
the first key that contains special characters.

Comment: I was not aware of the %K expansion option. Can you give an example of how to write this with three CONTAINS statements that only require one searchTerm parameter?

Comment: @itslittlejohn: See updated answer, you just have to repeat the arguments.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. The reason I was passing the string inline was so that I could avoid passing the search term multiple times. NSString stringWithFormat handles this nicely.

Comment: @itslittlejohn: But that will cause errors as soon as the search term contains quotation marks. (I would never mix `stringWithFormat` and `predicateWithFormat`.)